# Powershell - remove members from group that have an AD attribute

Tags: powershell

I would like to remove members from a group if they have any value in the employeeNumber attribute on AD. I can return all member of a group using Get-ADGroupMember but how do I then iterate through to remove members who have a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this to enumerate the group members who have the attribute set:

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'groupname' | Get-ADUser -Properties * |
    ? { $_.employeeNumber -ne $null }
```

To actually remove those members from the group, you'll have to add a second step like this:

```
$membersToRemove = Get-ADGroupMember 'groupname' `
  | Get-ADUser -Properties * `
  | ? { $_.employeeNumber -ne $null } `
  | % { $_.sAMAccountName }
Remove-ADGroupMember 'groupname' $membersToRemove
```

Comment: Are you sure it removes the members in question?

Comment: If that question was directed at me: as it is the code just enumerates members of a given group who have the attribute `employeeNumber` set. It doesn't remove anything.

Comment: Hi, yes have tested various scenarios. Are you suggesting it shouldn't?

Comment: Ah right, i already had the remove group code, it was the iteration through the right AD users that I couldn't get to grips with..

Comment: Get-ADGroupMember 'MyGroup' | Get-ADUser -Properties * | ? { $_.employeeNumber -ne $null } | % { Remove-ADGroupMember 'MyGroup' -Members $_ -Confirm:$false}

Comment: @user2145047 You can remove multiple members from a group with a single call by passing an array of identifiers into `Remove-ADGroupMember`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity group1 | 
Where-Object { (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $_.SamAccountName} -Properties EmployeeNumber).EmployeeNumber }

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity group1 -Members $members -Confirm:$false
```